# Matlab: overlay JPEG and image with scaled color

Tags: matlab, overlay, raster

I have a grayscale image represented by JPG file

```
img = imread(file); 
img_db = im2double(rgb2gray(img)));
```

which I want to overlay

```
figure
imshow(img_db);
hold on
```

with the result of imagesc() function (a result of interpolation)

```
xl = linspace(xmin, xmax, 300); 
yl = linspace(ymin, ymax, 300); 
[Xg, Yg] = meshgrid(xl,yl);
Zg = griddata(X, Y, Z, Xg, Yg, 'natural');
```

Both images have a different size. The resulting raster is set to be transparent

```
pl = imagesc(xl, yl, Zg, 'AlphaData', 0.3); 
colormap(turbo); 
colorbar;
```

However, despite its transparency, the second raster is not visible correctly. Only its boundaries can be recognized, but not the content.

I tried also

```
imshow(imoverlay(img, pl);
imshowpair(img, pl);
```

but both rasters should be of specific types (BW for imageoverlay).

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for such a beginner's question, but the main problem was here

```
img_db = im2double(rgb2gray(img)));
```

After converting the raster to the gray scale, the overlayed image was not displayed properly (I am not sure why).

However, after removing this line, everything is OK.